# How to reformat this code so I don't use 'Exit Try' and 'Exit For'?

Tags: vb.net, exception-handling

I use SonarQube to help me try and become a better programmer to program along with 'best-practice' standards.

There are business rules when a user is submitting data they enter in a datagridview that I encompass in a `Try Catch` block. I think the comments in the code describe fairly well what should be happening.

The problem: When I submit my project to SonarQube, it says "Exit Statements should not be used." I do not know what to use in lieu of the `Exit` statements, when they do exactly what I need. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

A visual representation of the Data Grid View:

```
Must be between 0-85             Must total to 100
+------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
| Bonus Percentage | Fund Option | Fund Percentage | Election Date|
+------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
|       85         |     2       |     50          |    3/20/2014 |
+------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
|       85         |     5       |     50          |    3/20/2014 |
+------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

Code:

```
tot = CInt(BonusDGV.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value)

'Business Rules Try/Catch block
Try
    'Ensure, for all rows, Fund amount totals 100 and Bonus Percentage is between 0-85%.
    For i As Integer = 0 To BonusDGV.Rows.Count - 1
        'don't count rows that contain no data
        If BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = Nothing Then
            Exit For
        End If
        fundTot = fundTot + CInt(BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
        If tot <> CInt(BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Percentage Must Be Between 0-85%.", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            'Stop looping, there has been a violation in user entry (Bonus Percentage)
            Exit Try
        End If
    Next
    'Bonus Percentage must be between 0-85% // \\ Double check
    If tot > 85 Or tot < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Percentage Must Be Between 0-85%.", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Try
        'Total of fun amounts must = 100
    ElseIf fundTot <> 100 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Fund Total Must Add to 100%.", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Try
        'Met all the business requirements, proceed to insert record
    Else
        For i As Integer = 0 To BonusDGV.Rows.Count - 1
            'Make sure there is actually data in the row
            If BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = Nothing Then
                Exit For
            End If
            cmd.Parameters("@BonusPct").Value = BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            cmd.Parameters("@FundID").Value = CInt(BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
            cmd.Parameters("@DefPct").Value = BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
            cmd.Parameters("@ElectDT").Value = BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
            'nonquery because we don't expect a return value
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry. Make sure Bonus Percentage is between 0-85% and Fund Percentage total = 100.", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
'dispose of the connection
conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your `Exit Try` statements follow an error condition. So why not throw an exception with the message and display it in the `Catch` block instead? That's the purpose of the `Try..Catch`.

Also, to get rid of the `Exit For`, just reverse the conditional. As it is, those two statements will end the loop completely on the first empty row, not just skip it.

(Ideally, you'd want to create a custom Exception class and throw it instead of a generic `Exception`, but this is just to give you an idea.)

So you end up with something like this

```
tot = CInt(BonusDGV.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value)

'Business Rules Try/Catch block
Try
    'Ensure, for all rows, Fund amount totals 100 and Bonus Percentage is between 0-85%.
    For i As Integer = 0 To BonusDGV.Rows.Count - 1
        'don't count rows that contain no data
        If BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing Then
          fundTot = fundTot + CInt(BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
          If tot <> CInt(BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value) Then
            Throw New Exception("Percentage Must Be Between 0-85%.")
          End If
        End If
    Next
    'Bonus Percentage must be between 0-85% // \\ Double check
    If tot > 85 Or tot < 0 Then
      Throw New Exception("Percentage Must Be Between 0-85%.")
    ElseIf fundTot <> 100 Then
      Throw New Exception("Fund Total Must Add to 100%.")
      'Met all the business requirements, proceed to insert record
    Else
        For i As Integer = 0 To BonusDGV.Rows.Count - 1
          'Make sure there is actually data in the row
          If BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing Then
            cmd.Parameters("@BonusPct").Value = BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            cmd.Parameters("@FundID").Value = CInt(BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
            cmd.Parameters("@DefPct").Value = BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
            cmd.Parameters("@ElectDT").Value = BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
            'nonquery because we don't expect a return value
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
          End If
        Next
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
'dispose of the connection
conn.Close()
```

Comment: I thought about doing the `IsNot Nothing`, which I should have known better. I'll have to do more research on `Throw New Exception`, I'm not too familiar with that. I'm assuming it skips the rest of the code once entered and goes immediately to the Catch block. Thanks! I Appreciate it. I would love to hear more about the `Exception` class I should be using in lieu of these Exceptions.

Comment: @MarkLaREZZA `Throw` is a way of manually creating an exception. You're correct that it will transfer control to the `Catch` block, just as if any other error in the code threw an exception. What I was referring to by custom exception is making your own class that inherits from `Exception` and using it. Then you have the ability to respond differently if you catch an exception of the custom class versus an unexpected exception generated elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Got it. I looked at the MSDN documentation, but it's somewhat over my head and kind of lacking in my opinion. I'll have to search for a better resource. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would seperate the error checking from the database connection.

```
Enum ErrorType
    Success
    NotBetween
    NotAdding
End Enum

Function IsThereAnError() As ErrorType

    tot = CInt(BonusDGV.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value)

    'Ensure, for all rows, Fund amount totals 100 and Bonus Percentage is between 0-85%.
    For i As Integer = 0 To BonusDGV.Rows.Count - 1
        'don't count rows that contain no data
        If BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = Nothing Then
            Exit For
        End If
        fundTot = fundTot + CInt(BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
        If tot <> CInt(BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value) Then
            Return ErrorType.NotBetween
            'Stop looping, there has been a violation in user entry (Bonus Percentage)
        End If
    Next
    'Bonus Percentage must be between 0-85% // \\ Double check
    If tot > 85 Or tot < 0 Then
        Return ErrorType.NotBetween
        'Total of fun amounts must = 100
    ElseIf fundTot <> 100 Then
        Return ErrorType.NotAdding
        'Met all the business requirements, proceed to insert record
    End If

    Return ErrorType.Success
End Function

Public Sub Save()

    ' OPEN DATABASE CONNECTION

    For i As Integer = 0 To BonusDGV.Rows.Count - 1
        'Make sure there is actually data in the row
        If BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = Nothing Then
            Exit For
        End If
        cmd.Parameters("@BonusPct").Value = BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        cmd.Parameters("@FundID").Value = CInt(BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
        cmd.Parameters("@DefPct").Value = BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
        cmd.Parameters("@ElectDT").Value = BonusDGV.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
        'nonquery because we don't expect a return value
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next

    ' CLOSE DATABASE CONNECTION

End Sub

Sub DoSomething()

    Select Case IsThereAnError()
        Case ErrorType.Success
            Save()
        Case ErrorType.NotBetween
            MessageBox.Show("Percentage Must Be Between 0-85%.", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Case ErrorType.NotAdding
            MessageBox.Show("Fund Total Must Add to 100%.", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Select
```